# Laravel route parameter except

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Trying to make dynamic URL, but I want it to accept the "admin" parameter.

```
Route::namespace('Web')->group(function () {
  Route::namespace('Home')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{sef?}/{sef2?}', 'HomepageController@index')->name('homepage');
  });
});
```

I don't want the code above affects the following code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('CMS')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('user')->namespace('Management')->group(function () {
      Route::get('/', 'UserController@profile')->name('user-dashboard');
    .......
```

But when I go to page like; `/admin/users` or `/admin` only the route `/{sef}/{sef2}` works. It doesn't see the `/admin` routing.

Comment: Change their order or use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: if these routes are in same file try to use admin route first cos laravel routes works order